# HTML/CSS fixed element doesnt hide other elements when scrolling

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm doing exercise from freeCodeCamp in HTML/CSS section. I have no knowledge of JS as of right now.

I made a fixed position navbar in my website, and when I scroll through the page it doesn't hide some of the elements "underneath" it.

[image]

I want both "premium materials" and the little icon on the left to be hidden when navbar is "above" them.

navbar css code:

```
#header{
  grid-area: nav;
  position: fixed;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 40% 40%;
  background-color: rgb(198, 198, 198);
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  top:0px;
  left: 0px;
  rifth: 0px;
}
```

What's going on there and how could I fix it?

Comment: can you give other element css (the pic)

Answer (score 1):

Your fixed navbar needs to be stacked on top of all other elements on your page. Add a [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) css property to your `#header` element like this:

```
#header{
    z-index: 1; // keep increasing this by 1 for as long as there are elements still overlapping the navbar

    /* other css properties below */
}
```

Comment: @ReversingHorse Glad I could help. Cheers.

Comment: @ReversingHorse Do mark this as the correct answer if it helped you solve your issue.